# React Task List not updating correctly

Tags: reactjs

I am making task list using only react (no backend). Right now I’m working on adding a new task using state, which the list does update but the new task doesn’t display the task string that it should be and the delete button is on the wrong side. I know all the data is there because of react dev tools but it isn't displaying correctly. I really can't figure out why all the data is passing but not be displayed.

This is the end result:

[image: Task List]

Task Component:

```
import { FaTimes } from 'react-icons/fa';

const Task = ({ task, onDelete, onToggle }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`task ${task.reminder ? 'reminder' : ''}`}
      onDoubleClick={() => onToggle(task.id)}
    >
      <h3>
        {task.text}{' '}
        <FaTimes
          style={{ color: 'red', cursor: 'pointer' }}
          onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)}
        />
      </h3>
      <p>{task.day}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Task;
```

Tasks Component:

```
import Task from './Task';

const Tasks = ({ tasks, onDelete, onToggle }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Task
          key={task.id}
          task={task}
          onDelete={onDelete}
          onToggle={onToggle}
        />
      ))}
    </> 
  );
};

export default Tasks;
```

AddTask Component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const AddTask = ({ onAdd }) => {
  const [task, setTask] = useState('');
  const [day, setDay] = useState('');
  const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(false);

  /**
   * onSubmit
   *
   * @param {Event from submit button} e
   * @returns
   */
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!task) {
      alert('Please add a task');
      return;
    }

    onAdd({ task, day, reminder });

    setTask('');
    setDay('');
    setReminder(false);
  };

  return (
    <form className="add-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div className="form-control">
        <label>Task</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add task"
          value={task}
          onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-control">
        <label>Day & Time</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Day & Time"
          value={day}
          onChange={(e) => setDay(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="form-control form-control-check">
        <label>Set Reminder</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={reminder}
          value={reminder}
          onChange={(e) => setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)}
        />
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Add Task" className="btn btn-block" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddTask;
```

App:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks';
import AddTask from './components/AddTask';

const App = () => {

  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    { 
      id: 1,
      text: 'Doctors Appointment',
      day: 'Feb 5th at 2:30',
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Meeting at School',
      day: 'Feb 6th at 1:30',
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Food Shopping',
      day: 'Feb 5th at 2:30',
      reminder: false,
    },
  ]);

  /**
   * Add Task
   *
   * @param {Task} task
   */
  const addTask = (task) => {

    console.log(task)
    
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;

    const newTask = { id, ...task };

    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  };

  /**
   * Delete Task
   *
   * @param {Task ID} id
   */
  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  /**
   * Toggle Reminder
   *
   * @param {TaskID} id
   */
  const toggleReminder = (id) => {
    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) =>
        task.id === id ? { ...task, reminder: !task.reminder } : task
      )
    );
  };

  // REMINDER: you can only return one element from the function
  return (
    // this will return the header component that we designed
    <div className="container ">
      <Header />
      <AddTask onAdd={addTask} />
      {tasks.length > 0 ? (
        <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} onToggle={toggleReminder} />
      ) : (
        'No Tasks to show'
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you clarify what "the contents are messed up" means? What is happening? What were you expecting? What are the reproduction steps to cause the issue you see?

Comment: It looks like your `AddTask` component is putting your new task text in `task.task` rather than `task.text`. You could change it to `onAdd({ text: task, day, reminder });`

Comment: @Nick Thank you very much! That fixed it. It's interesting that the naming I used was the conflict, maybe in the future I'll just call it text rather than text.